# Warning: move_uploaded_file(sample_material/13-1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\tms\

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I tried uploading files to a folder, it ain't uploading throwing some errors as shown at the bottom of the post. But without the file upload, the submission of data to database is working, so the only problem is the moving of my file to the folder. I also need to check if the file is a picture and a code to compress the size of the image to a desired size. Below are the details;

Form that collects data for me below:

```
    <form action="orderadd1.php?id=<?php echo "".$order_id; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<button class="add_field_button">Add another sub-order</button>
<div style="margin-top:20px;">
  <label>Upload Sample Material</label><br />
  <input type="file" name="sample_material[]" style="width:200px; height: 40px;"/>
  <br/><br/>
  <label>Customer's Requirement</label><br />
  <textarea name="cust_requirement[]" style="width:200px; height: 150px;" /></textarea><br/><br/>
  <label>Do you have a style</label><br />
  <select name="sketch_code[]" id="sketch_code" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this)">
    <option value="">I don't have a style code</option>
    <option value="iHaveStyle">I have a style code</option>
  </select>
  <div id="div1"></div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-color btn-block" value="Continue Order" name="submit_val">
</form>
```

JQuery adds extra fields for me here:

```
<script>
function showfield(name,event){

if(name=='iHaveStyle') {
$(event).next('#div1').html('<label>Enter Style Code</label><br /> <input type="text" name="style[]" style="width:200px; height: 40px;" />');
} else{
 $(event).next('#div1').html('');
}

}
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".form-group"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
  e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div style="margin-top:20px; border-top:1px solid #333333;"><label>Upload Sample Material</label><br /><input type="file" name="sample_material[]" style="width:200px; height: 40px;" /><br/><br/><label>Customer&#39s Requirement</label><br /><textarea name="cust_requirement[]" style="width:200px; height: 150px;" /></textarea><br/><br/><label>Do you have a style</label><br /><select name="sketch_code[]" id="sketch_code" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this)"><option value="">I don&#39t have a style code</option><option value="iHaveStyle">I have a style code</option></select><div id="div1"></div><br /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
      }
    });
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove  text
  e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
});
</script>
```

PHP Codes below:

```
$order_id = $_REQUEST['id'];

if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {

$k=1;
for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['style']); $i++ ) {

$cust_requirement = $_POST['cust_requirement'][$i];
$style = $_POST['style'][$i];

foreach($_FILES['sample_material']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
{
$folder = "sample_material/";
$extention = strrchr($_FILES['sample_material']['name'][$key], ".");
$name = basename($_FILES["sample_material"]["name"][$key]);
$new_name = $order_id."-".$k++;
$sample_material = $new_name.'.jpg';
$uploaddir = $folder . $sample_material;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sample_material']['tmp_name'][$key], $uploaddir);


$data_submit = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO `order_desc` (order_id, cust_requirements, style_code) VALUES ('".$order_id."', '".$cust_requirement."', '".$style."')");
}

}
}

?>
```

The error is below:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(sample_material/13-1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\tms\orderadd1.php on line 61

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php577C.tmp' to 'sample_material/13-1.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\tms\orderadd1.php on line 61
```

Comment: Do one thing! after `$uploaddir = $folder . $sample_material;` add this `var_dump($uploaddir)` and check what variable is being set up in it.

Comment: It sees it: This is the result I get; string(24) "sample_material/13-1.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of changes made it work: See the code below;

```
<?php

$order_id = $_REQUEST['id'];

if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {

$k=0;

for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['style']); $i++ ) {
$k++;
$cust_requirement = $_POST['cust_requirement'][$i];
$style = $_POST['style'][$i];

foreach($_FILES['sample_material']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
{
$folder = "sample_material/";
$extention = strrchr($_FILES['sample_material']['tmp_name'][$key], ".");
$name = basename($_FILES["sample_material"]["name"][$key]);
$new_name = $order_id."-".$k;
$sample_material = $new_name.'.jpg';
$uploaddir = $folder . $sample_material;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sample_material']['tmp_name'][$key], $uploaddir);

}
$data_submit = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO `order_desc` (`order_id`, `cust_requirements`, `style_code`, `sample_photo_url`) VALUES ('".$order_id."', '".$cust_requirement."', '".$style."', '".$uploaddir."')");
}
}

?>
```